# Please help new install 12.10 black screen

Tags: upgrade

Hey guys new to the forum and new to ubuntu, 
I installed 12.10 via a USB and all went well anyway since the installation has finished all I keep getting is a black screen I have a old dell laptop , dell latitude d610 , I really don't know what to do so any help would be great because now I have a laptop what doesn't work

Thanks guys

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dell Latitude will not boot after fresh Ubuntu 12.10 installation. Black screen](http://askubuntu.com/questions/211252/dell-latitude-will-not-boot-after-fresh-ubuntu-12-10-installation-black-screen)

Comment: possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

Let things load up (I know you can't see it). When you think it has (couple of mins fine) do

```
    `Ctrl+Alt+F2`
```

This will bring up the console. Login and then you can attempt to correct the problem. Probably likely to be graphics related. When you installed did you let the install disk boot up to the op system or did you just go straight for the install? If you went straight for the install the system may just be wigging out with your particular laptop.

Comment: Hi thanks for getting back to me, I've tried Cyril alt f2 and nothing ? Have u got an email I could send a vid to please, also I booted from a USB and installed from there what can I do?

Comment: I've just got onto it and its crashed and won't go back on

Answer (score 0):

I think you better supply a bit more detail. What dell laptop - graphics card etc, what install media have you tried - 32/64bit, have you tried the alternate install? Usb stick? Or Usb cd? Do you get to grub? (the boot loader) hold down shift immediately after post to bring up ubuntu grub menu.